# How to use multiprocessing pool.map with multiple arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In the Python [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library, is there a variant of `pool.map` which supports multiple arguments?

```
import multiprocessing

text = "test"

def harvester(text, case):
    X = case[0]
    text + str(X)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
    case = RAW_DATASET
    pool.map(harvester(text, case), case, 1)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: To my surprise, I could make neither `partial` nor `lambda` do this. I think it has to do with the strange way that functions are passed to the subprocesses (via `pickle`).

Comment: @senderle: This is a bug in Python 2.6, but has been fixed as of 2.7: http://bugs.python.org/issue5228

Comment: Just simply replace  
`pool.map(harvester(text,case),case, 1)`  
by:  
`pool.apply_async(harvester(text,case),case, 1)`

Comment: @Syrtis_Major , please don't edit OP questions which effectively skew answers that have been previously given.  Adding `return` to `harvester()` turned @senderie 's response into being inaccurate. That does not help future readers.

Comment: I would say easy solution would be to pack all the args in a tuple and unpack it in the executing func. I did this when I needed to send complicated multiple args to a func being executed by a pool of  processes.

Comment: Maybe there is some complexity I am missing for this particular use case but partial works for my similar use case and is very succint and easy to use.

http://python.omics.wiki/multiprocessing_map/multiprocessing_partial_function_multiple_arguments

Answer (score 508, accepted):

The answer to this is version- and situation-dependent. The most general answer for recent versions of Python (since 3.3) was first described below by [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443941/577088).<sup>1</sup> It uses the [`Pool.starmap`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) method, which accepts a sequence of argument tuples. It then automatically unpacks the arguments from each tuple and passes them to the given function:

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import product

def merge_names(a, b):
    return '{} & {}'.format(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = ['Brown', 'Wilson', 'Bartlett', 'Rivera', 'Molloy', 'Opie']
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(merge_names, product(names, repeat=2))
    print(results)

# Output: ['Brown & Brown', 'Brown & Wilson', 'Brown & Bartlett', ...
```

For earlier versions of Python, you'll need to write a helper function to unpack the arguments explicitly. If you want to use `with`, you'll also need to write a wrapper to turn `Pool` into a context manager. (Thanks to [muon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments/5442981?noredirect=1#comment80290057_5442981) for pointing this out.)

```
import multiprocessing
from itertools import product
from contextlib import contextmanager

def merge_names(a, b):
    return '{} & {}'.format(a, b)

def merge_names_unpack(args):
    return merge_names(*args)

@contextmanager
def poolcontext(*args, **kwargs):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(*args, **kwargs)
    yield pool
    pool.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = ['Brown', 'Wilson', 'Bartlett', 'Rivera', 'Molloy', 'Opie']
    with poolcontext(processes=3) as pool:
        results = pool.map(merge_names_unpack, product(names, repeat=2))
    print(results)

# Output: ['Brown & Brown', 'Brown & Wilson', 'Brown & Bartlett', ...
```

In simpler cases, with a fixed second argument, you can also use `partial`, but only in Python 2.7+.

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def poolcontext(*args, **kwargs):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(*args, **kwargs)
    yield pool
    pool.terminate()

def merge_names(a, b):
    return '{} & {}'.format(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = ['Brown', 'Wilson', 'Bartlett', 'Rivera', 'Molloy', 'Opie']
    with poolcontext(processes=3) as pool:
        results = pool.map(partial(merge_names, b='Sons'), names)
    print(results)

# Output: ['Brown & Sons', 'Wilson & Sons', 'Bartlett & Sons', ...
```

<sup>1. Much of this was inspired by his answer, which should probably have been accepted instead. But since this one is stuck at the top, it seemed best to improve it for future readers.</sup>

Comment: It seems to me that RAW_DATASET in this case should be a global variable? While I want the partial_harvester change the value of case in every call of harvester(). How to achieve that?

Comment: The most important thing here is assigning `=RAW_DATASET` default value to `case`. Otherwise `pool.map` will confuse about the multiple arguments.

Comment: I'm confused, what happened to the `text` variable in your example? Why is `RAW_DATASET` seemingly passed twice. I think you might have a typo?

Comment: not sure why using `with .. as ..`  gives me `AttributeError: __exit__`, but works fine  if i just call `pool = Pool();` then close manually `pool.close()` (python2.7)

Comment: @muon, good catch. It appears `Pool` objects don't become context managers until Python 3.3. I've added a simple wrapper function that returns a `Pool` context manager.

Comment: @muon How to use call_back in pool.starmap

Comment: Does this starmap support generator function which yield infinite sequence

Comment: @machen, it depends on what you mean. But I wouldn't recommend using infinite generators with multiprocessing unless they are paired with finite generators. For example, you could probably do something like `pool.starmap(twoarg_func, zip(finite, infinite))`. It's possible that `pool.imap` and `pool.imap_unordered` could tolerate infinite generators but that still sounds like a [pretty bad idea](https://i.imgur.com/y4iPS0u.jpg) to me.

Comment: Does the order of arguments in functions call?

Answer (score 824):

> is there a variant of pool.map which support multiple arguments?

Python 3.3 includes [`pool.starmap()` method](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from functools import partial
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

def func(a, b):
    return a + b

def main():
    a_args = [1,2,3]
    second_arg = 1
    with Pool() as pool:
        L = pool.starmap(func, [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)])
        M = pool.starmap(func, zip(a_args, repeat(second_arg)))
        N = pool.map(partial(func, b=second_arg), a_args)
        assert L == M == N

if __name__=="__main__":
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

For older versions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

def func(a, b):
    print a, b

def func_star(a_b):
    """Convert `f([1,2])` to `f(1,2)` call."""
    return func(*a_b)

def main():
    pool = Pool()
    a_args = [1,2,3]
    second_arg = 1
    pool.map(func_star, itertools.izip(a_args, itertools.repeat(second_arg)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

#### Output

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
```

Notice how [`itertools.izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) and [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) are used here.

Due to [the bug mentioned by @unutbu](http://bugs.python.org/issue5228) you can't use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) or similar capabilities on Python 2.6, so the simple wrapper function `func_star()` should be defined explicitly. See also [the workaround](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/351774/) [suggested by `uptimebox`](http://bugs.python.org/issue5228#msg130548).

Comment: F.: You can unpack the argument tuple in the signature of `func_star` like this: `def func_star((a, b))`. Of course, this only works for a fixed number of arguments, but if that is the only case he has, it is more readable.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: `f((a,b))` syntax is deprecated and removed in py3k. And it is unnecessary here.

Comment: perhaps more pythonic: `func = lambda x: func(*x)` instead of defining a wrapper function

Comment: @dylam: read the last paragraph in the answer or try your suggestion on Python 2.6 (it fails)

Comment: So ... the above doesn't work if you are calling a class function within a class (wants self passed as an argument?)

Comment: @zthomas.nc this question is about how to support multiple arguments for multiprocessing pool.map. If want to know how to call a method instead of a function in a different Python process via multiprocessing then ask a separate question (if all else fails, you could always create a global function that wraps the method call similar to `func_star()` above)

Comment: Does this starmap support generator function which yield infinite sequence?

Comment: @machen starmap supports generators (such as zip() above). It returns a *list* and therefore you shouldn't pass it an infinite generator (it  will just consume all memory)

Comment: @jfs This is a bit unrelated but I want to run a function that **does not take any arguments** in the background but I have some resource limitations and cannot run the function as many times that I want and want to queue the extra executions of the function. Do you have any idea on how I should do that? I have my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081260/executing-a-function-in-the-background-while-using-limited-number-of-cores-threa). Could you please take a look at my question and see if you can give me some hints (or even better, an answer) on how I should do that?

Comment: I wish there were `starstarmap`.

Comment: @КонстантинВан starstar is to accept an iterable of dicts with parameters?

Comment: @jfs Right. Keyword arguments.

Comment: is this still the best way to do this today? what is freeze_support?

Comment: @mike01010 yes, the reason for using [`freeze_support()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) is still there. Follow the link, to find out more details.

Answer (score 191):

I think the below will be better:

```
def multi_run_wrapper(args):
   return add(*args)

def add(x,y):
    return x+y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(multi_run_wrapper,[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)])
    print results
```

Output

```
[3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Easiest solution. There is a small optimization; remove the wrapper function and unpack `args` directly in `add`, it works for any number of arguments:
`def add(args):
(x,y) = args`

Comment: you could also use a `lambda` function instead of defining `multi_run_wrapper(..)`

Comment: hm... in fact, using a `lambda` does not work because `pool.map(..)` tries to pickle the given function

Comment: How do you use this if you want to store the result of `add` in a list?

Comment: @Ahmed I like it how it is, because IMHO the method call should fail, whenever the number of parameter is not correct.

Comment: please add ```pool.close()``` and ```pool.join()``` after getting **results = pool.map(...)**, else this might possibly runs forever

Comment: @WilliamLe good point, but the pythonic way to do it is using the context manager (as in the edit).

Answer (score 127):

Using **Python 3.3+** with `pool.starmap():`

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

def write_func(i, x):
    print(i, "---", x)

a = ["1","2","3"]
b = ["4","5","6"] 

pool = ThreadPool(2)
pool.starmap(write_func, zip(a,b)) 
pool.close() 
pool.join()
```

Result:

```
1 --- 4
2 --- 5
3 --- 6
```

You can also zip() more arguments if you like: `zip(a,b,c,d,e)`

In case you want to have a **constant value** passed as an argument:

```
import itertools

zip(itertools.repeat(constant), a)
```

In case your function should **return** something:

```
results = pool.starmap(write_func, zip(a,b))
```

This gives a List with the returned values.

Comment: This is a near exact duplicate answer as the one from @J.F.Sebastian in 2011 (with 60+ votes).

Comment: No. First of all it removed lots of unnecessary stuff and clearly states it's for python 3.3+ and is intended for beginners that look for a simple and clean answer. As a beginner myself it took some time to figure it out that way (yes with JFSebastians posts) and this is why I wrote my post to help other beginners, because his post simply said "there is starmap" but did not explain it - this is what my post intends. So there is absolutely no reason to bash me with two downvotes.

Answer (score 92):

How to take multiple arguments:

```
def f1(args):
    a, b, c = args[0] , args[1] , args[2]
    return a+b+c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4) 

    result1 = pool.map(f1, [ [1,2,3] ])
    print(result1)
```

Comment: Neat and elegant.

Comment: I don't understand why I have to scroll all the way over here to find the best answer.

Comment: This answer should literally have been at the top most.

Comment: Still, an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What languages features does it use and why? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://XXXX), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 32):

Having learnt about itertools in [J.F. Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443941/446149) I decided to take it a step further and write a `parmap` package that takes care about parallelization, offering `map` and `starmap` functions in Python 2.7 and Python 3.2 (and later also) that can take *any number* of positional arguments.

Installation

```
pip install parmap
```

How to parallelize:

```
import parmap
# If you want to do:
y = [myfunction(x, argument1, argument2) for x in mylist]
# In parallel:
y = parmap.map(myfunction, mylist, argument1, argument2)

# If you want to do:
z = [myfunction(x, y, argument1, argument2) for (x,y) in mylist]
# In parallel:
z = parmap.starmap(myfunction, mylist, argument1, argument2)

# If you want to do:
listx = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
listy = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
param = 3.14
param2 = 42
listz = []
for (x, y) in zip(listx, listy):
        listz.append(myfunction(x, y, param1, param2))
# In parallel:
listz = parmap.starmap(myfunction, zip(listx, listy), param1, param2)
```

I have uploaded parmap to PyPI and to [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/zeehio/parmap).

As an example, the question can be answered as follows:

```
import parmap

def harvester(case, text):
    X = case[0]
    text+ str(X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    case = RAW_DATASET  # assuming this is an iterable
    parmap.map(harvester, case, "test", chunksize=1)
```

Answer (score 19):

There's a fork of `multiprocessing` called [pathos](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos) (*note: use the version on GitHub*) that doesn't need `starmap` -- the map functions mirror the API for Python's map, thus map can take multiple arguments.

With `pathos`, you can also generally do multiprocessing in the interpreter, instead of being stuck in the `__main__` block. Pathos is due for a release, after some mild updating -- mostly conversion to Python 3.x.

```
  Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 30 2013, 20:15:49)
  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5566)] on darwin
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> def func(a,b):
  ...     print a,b
  ...
  >>>
  >>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
  >>> pool = ProcessingPool(nodes=4)
  >>> pool.map(func, [1,2,3], [1,1,1])
  1 1
  2 1
  3 1
  [None, None, None]
  >>>
  >>> # also can pickle stuff like lambdas
  >>> result = pool.map(lambda x: x**2, range(10))
  >>> result
  [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
  >>>
  >>> # also does asynchronous map
  >>> result = pool.amap(pow, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
  >>> result.get()
  [1, 32, 729]
  >>>
  >>> # or can return a map iterator
  >>> result = pool.imap(pow, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
  >>> result
  <processing.pool.IMapIterator object at 0x110c2ffd0>
  >>> list(result)
  [1, 32, 729]
```

`pathos` has several ways that that you can get the exact behavior of `starmap`.

```
>>> def add(*x):
...   return sum(x)
...
>>> x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> import pathos
>>> import numpy as np
>>> # use ProcessPool's map and transposing the inputs
>>> pp = pathos.pools.ProcessPool()
>>> pp.map(add, *np.array(x).T)
[6, 15]
>>> # use ProcessPool's map and a lambda to apply the star
>>> pp.map(lambda x: add(*x), x)
[6, 15]
>>> # use a _ProcessPool, which has starmap
>>> _pp = pathos.pools._ProcessPool()
>>> _pp.starmap(add, x)
[6, 15]
>>>
```

Comment: I want to note that this doesn't address the structure in the original question. [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] would unpack with starmap to [pow(1,2,3), pow(4,5,6)], not [pow(1,4), pow(2,5), pow(3, 6)]. If you don't have good control over the inputs being passed to to your function, you may need to restructure them first.

Comment: @Scott: ah, I didn't notice that... over 5 years ago. I'll make a small update.  Thanks.

Comment: Should zip input vectors. More understandable than transposing and array, don't you think?

Comment: The array transpose, while possibly less clear, should be less expensive.

Answer (score 12):

Let's keep it simple and straightforward, refer my soltuon :

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from functools import partial
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def dosomething(var,s):
    sleep(randint(1,5))
    print(var)
    return var + s

array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
with ThreadPool(processes=5) as pool:
    resp_ = pool.map(partial(dosomething,s="2"), array)
    print(resp_)
```

Output:

```
a
b
d
e
c
['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2']
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to pass a list of lists to a one-argument routine:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def task(args):
    print "PID =", os.getpid(), ", arg1 =", args[0], ", arg2 =", args[1]

pool = Pool()

pool.map(task, [
        [1,2],
        [3,4],
        [5,6],
        [7,8]
    ])
```

One can then construct a list lists of arguments with one's favorite method.

Comment: This is an easy way, but you need to change your original functions. What's more, some time recall others' functions which may can't be modified.

Comment: I will say this sticks to Python zen. There should be one and only one obvious way to do it. If by chance you are the author of the calling function, this you should use this method, for other cases we can use imotai's method.

Comment: My choice is to use a tuple, And then immediately unwrap them as the first thing in the first line.

Comment: What do you mean by *"a list lists of arguments"* (seems incomprehensible)? Preferably, please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22391818/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 10):

A better way is using a **decorator** instead of writing a **wrapper function** by hand. Especially when you have a lot of functions to map, a decorator will save your time by avoiding writing a wrapper for every function. Usually a decorated function is not picklable, however we may use `functools` to get around it. More discussions can be found [here](http://gael-varoquaux.info/programming/decoration-in-python-done-right-decorating-and-pickling.html).

Here is the example:

```
def unpack_args(func):
    from functools import wraps
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(args):
        if isinstance(args, dict):
            return func(**args)
        else:
            return func(*args)
    return wrapper

@unpack_args
def func(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Then you may map it with zipped arguments:

```
np, xlist, ylist = 2, range(10), range(10)
pool = Pool(np)
res = pool.map(func, zip(xlist, ylist))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Of course, you may always use [`Pool.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) in Python 3 (>=3.3) as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Results are not as expected:
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
I would expect: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, ...

Comment: @TedoVrbanec Results just should be [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]. If you want the later one, you may use `itertools.product` instead of `zip`.

Comment: `starmap` was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

A better solution for Python 2:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def func((i, (a, b))):
    print i, a, b
    return a + b
pool = Pool(3)
pool.map(func, [(0,(1,2)), (1,(2,3)), (2,(3, 4))])
```

#### Output

```
2 3 4

1 2 3

0 1 2

out[]:

[3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following two functions so as to avoid writing a wrapper for each new function:

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool

def universal_worker(input_pair):
    function, args = input_pair
    return function(*args)

def pool_args(function, *args):
    return zip(itertools.repeat(function), zip(*args))
```

Use the function `function` with the lists of arguments `arg_0`, `arg_1` and `arg_2` as follows:

```
pool = Pool(n_core)
list_model = pool.map(universal_worker, pool_args(function, arg_0, arg_1, arg_2)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 9):

Another simple alternative is to wrap your function parameters in a tuple and then wrap the parameters that should be passed in tuples as well. This is perhaps not ideal when dealing with large pieces of data. I believe it would make copies for each tuple.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f((a,b,c,d)):
    print a,b,c,d
    return a + b + c +d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(10)
    data = [(i+0,i+1,i+2,i+3) for i in xrange(10)]
    print(p.map(f, data))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Gives the output in some random order:

```
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
7 8 9 10
6 7 8 9
8 9 10 11
9 10 11 12
[6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42]
```

Comment: Indeed it does, still looking for a better way :(

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way to do it that IMHO is more simple and elegant than any of the other answers provided.

This program has a function that takes two parameters, prints them out and also prints the sum:

```
import multiprocessing

def main():

    with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as pool:
        params = [ (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4) ]
        pool.starmap(printSum, params)
    # end with

# end function

def printSum(num1, num2):
    mySum = num1 + num2
    print('num1 = ' + str(num1) + ', num2 = ' + str(num2) + ', sum = ' + str(mySum))
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output is:

```
num1 = 2, num2 = 2, sum = 4
num1 = 3, num2 = 3, sum = 6
num1 = 4, num2 = 4, sum = 8
```

See the python docs for more info:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

In particular be sure to check out the `starmap` function.

I'm using Python 3.6, I'm not sure if this will work with older Python versions

Why there is not a very straight-forward example like this in the docs, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

From Python 3.4.4, you can use multiprocessing.get_context() to obtain a context object to use multiple start methods:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(q, h, w):
    q.put(h + ' ' + w)
    print(h + ' ' + w)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    q = ctx.Queue()
    p = ctx.Process(target=foo, args=(q,'hello', 'world'))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
```

Or you just simply replace

```
pool.map(harvester(text, case), case, 1)
```

with:

```
pool.apply_async(harvester(text, case), case, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the official documentation states that it supports only one iterable argument. I like to use apply_async in such cases. In your case I would do:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool, Manager

text = "test"
def harvester(text, case, q = None):
 X = case[0]
 res = text+ str(X)
 if q:
  q.put(res)
 return res


def block_until(q, results_queue, until_counter=0):
 i = 0
 while i < until_counter:
  results_queue.put(q.get())
  i+=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
 pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
 case = RAW_DATASET
 m = Manager()
 q = m.Queue()
 results_queue = m.Queue() # when it completes results will reside in this queue
 blocking_process = Process(block_until, (q, results_queue, len(case)))
 blocking_process.start()
 for c in case:
  try:
   res = pool.apply_async(harvester, (text, case, q = None))
   res.get(timeout=0.1)
  except:
   pass
 blocking_process.join()
```

Comment: You mean `c` instead of `case` here, right?: `res = pool.apply_async(harvester, (text, case, q = None))`

Answer (score 3):

There are many answers here, but none seem to provide Python 2/3 compatible code that will work on any version. If you want your code to *just work*, this will work for either Python version:

```py
# For python 2/3 compatibility, define pool context manager
# to support the 'with' statement in Python 2
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    from contextlib import contextmanager
    @contextmanager
    def multiprocessing_context(*args, **kwargs):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(*args, **kwargs)
        yield pool
        pool.terminate()
else:
    multiprocessing_context = multiprocessing.Pool
```

After that, you can use multiprocessing the regular Python 3 way, however you like. For example:

```
def _function_to_run_for_each(x):
       return x.lower()
with multiprocessing_context(processes=3) as pool:
    results = pool.map(_function_to_run_for_each, ['Bob', 'Sue', 'Tim'])    print(results)
```

will work in Python 2 or Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

```
text = "test"

def unpack(args):
    return args[0](*args[1:])

def harvester(text, case):
    X = case[0]
    text+ str(X)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
    case = RAW_DATASET
    # args is a list of tuples 
    # with the function to execute as the first item in each tuple
    args = [(harvester, text, c) for c in case]
    # doing it this way, we can pass any function
    # and we don't need to define a wrapper for each different function
    # if we need to use more than one
    pool.map(unpack, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the routine I use to pass multiple arguments to a one-argument function used in a [pool.imap](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) fork:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Wrapper of the function to map:
class makefun:
    def __init__(self, var2):
        self.var2 = var2
    def fun(self, i):
        var2 = self.var2
        return var1[i] + var2

# Couple of variables for the example:
var1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
var2 = [9, 10, 11, 12]

# Open the pool:
pool = Pool(processes=2)

# Wrapper loop
for j in range(len(var2)):
    # Obtain the function to map
    pool_fun = makefun(var2[j]).fun

    # Fork loop
    for i, value in enumerate(pool.imap(pool_fun, range(len(var1))), 0):
        print(var1[i], '+' ,var2[j], '=', value)

# Close the pool
pool.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be another option. The trick is in the `wrapper` function that returns another function which is passed in to `pool.map`. The code below reads an input array and for each (unique) element in it, returns how many times (ie counts) that element appears in the array, For example if the input is

```
np.eye(3) = [ [1. 0. 0.]
              [0. 1. 0.]
              [0. 0. 1.]]
```

then zero appears 6 times and one 3 times

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


def extract_counts(label_array):
    labels = np.unique(label_array)
    out = extract_counts_helper([label_array], labels)
    return out

def extract_counts_helper(args, labels):
    n = max(1, cpu_count() - 1)
    pool = ThreadPool(n)
    results = {}
    pool.map(wrapper(args, results), labels)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results

def wrapper(argsin, results):
    def inner_fun(label):
        label_array = argsin[0]
        counts = get_label_counts(label_array, label)
        results[label] = counts
    return inner_fun

def get_label_counts(label_array, label):
    return sum(label_array.flatten() == label)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = np.ones([2,2])
    out = extract_counts(img)
    print('input array: \n', img)
    print('label counts: ', out)
    print("========")
           
    img = np.eye(3)
    out = extract_counts(img)
    print('input array: \n', img)
    print('label counts: ', out)
    print("========")
    
    img = np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 3))
    out = extract_counts(img)
    print('input array: \n', img)
    print('label counts: ', out)
    print("========")
```

You should get:

```
input array: 
 [[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
label counts:  {1.0: 4}
========
input array: 
 [[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
label counts:  {0.0: 6, 1.0: 3}
========
input array: 
 [[4 4 0]
 [2 4 3]
 [2 3 1]]
label counts:  {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3}
========
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f1(args):
    vfirst, vsecond, vthird = args[0] , args[1] , args[2]
    print(f'First Param: {vfirst}, Second value: {vsecond} and finally third value is: {vthird}')
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()
    result = p.map(f1, [['Dog','Cat','Mouse']])
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print(result)
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68318726/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Store all your arguments as an *array of tuples*.

The example says normally you call your function as:

```
def mainImage(fragCoord: vec2, iResolution: vec3, iTime: float) -> vec3:
```

Instead pass one tuple and unpack the arguments:

```
def mainImage(package_iter) -> vec3:
    fragCoord = package_iter[0]
    iResolution = package_iter[1]
    iTime = package_iter[2]
```

Build up the tuple by using a loop beforehand:

```
package_iter = []
iResolution = vec3(nx, ny, 1)
for j in range((ny-1), -1, -1):
    for i in range(0, nx, 1):
        fragCoord: vec2 = vec2(i, j)
        time_elapsed_seconds = 10
        package_iter.append((fragCoord, iResolution, time_elapsed_seconds))
```

Then execute all using map by passing the *array of tuples*:

```
array_rgb_values = []

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for val in executor.map(mainImage, package_iter):
        fragColor = val
        ir = clip(int(255* fragColor.r), 0, 255)
        ig = clip(int(255* fragColor.g), 0, 255)
        ib = clip(int(255* fragColor.b), 0, 255)

        array_rgb_values.append((ir, ig, ib))
```

I know Python has `*` and `**` for unpacking, but I haven't tried those yet.

Also better to use the higher-level library concurrent futures than the low level multiprocessing library.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach- this example aims to download a bunch of files.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def download_file(batch):
    items_to_grab, var1, var2, etc. = batch
    ...

##batch yourself instead of using pool.map's chunk argument
batches = list(batch(items_to_grab, 200))
##now create tuples out of each chunk and add other variables you want to send along
batches =  [(x, var1, var2, etc.) for x in batches]
with Pool(5) as p:
     results = p.map(download_file, batches)
```

Answer (score -2):

For Python 2, you can use this trick

```
def fun(a, b):
    return a + b

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)
b = 233
pool.map(lambda x:fun(x, b), range(1000))
```

Comment: why b=233. defeats the purpose of the question